# How do I return a closure from a function?

Tags: c++, function, lambda

I want my getEnd function to return a closure with start saved.

When I call this closure it should return time difference...

How to implement it in the c++?

Something like followed:

```
using namespace std;

long microtime() {
  timeval time;
  gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
  long microsec = ((unsigned long long)time.tv_sec * 1000000) + time.tv_usec;
  return microsec;
}


std::function<void()> getEnd (){
  long start = microtime();
  long end() {
    return microtime() - start;
  }
  return end;
};
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? (For thost that don't have a compiler ready to try it...)

Comment: To start with, you *do* know how to write a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, great thanks for right question title)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <functional>
std::function<long()>  getEnd()
{
    long const start = microtime();
    return [=]{ return microtime() - start; };
}
```

Please note that the above will allocate memory on the heap, so for most practical applications a better alternative would be

```
struct timer {
     long const start;
     timer(): start(microtime()) {}
     long operator()() { return microtime - start();  }
};

timer getEnd() { return timer(); }
```

Comment: I've got `.cpp:15:1: error: ‘function’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type` on a codeline `std::function<long()>  getEnd()` How to right declare a function that returns lambda?

Comment: you are missing `#include <functional>`

Comment: thanks for struct as a function example, but my general aim is learning about lambdas... How to right declare a function that returns lambda? Your first code returns error yet(I already add `#include <functional>`)

Comment: are you using `gcc`? are you specifying -`std=c++11` flag when compiling?

Comment: I'm use `g++` and yes, I forgot this flag

Comment: also, tell please, how to use it? Is this right: `auto end = getEnd();` ? Or should I do `std::function<long()> end = getEnd();` ?

Comment: @vp_arth Both work, `auto` is fine and even [recommended by some of the best](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/).